# Do the number of cuts in a graph depend on the edges?

Tags: graph-theory

I found out the formula of number of cuts to be $\frac{2^n-2}{2}$ and I understand the logic. But should the number of cuts not depend on the edges.

Consider the following connected graph with 4 vertices. The edges are:

1 to 2

2 to 3

3 to 4

4 to 1

My point is that we can never create a cut in which (1,3) are in one connected component and (2,4) in another. And we are counting them in the above formula. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cut is a partition of the vertices of a graph into two disjoint nonempty subsets.  It has nothing to do with the edges, or with connectedness.
In your example, $\{1,3\}, \{2,4\}$ is a cut.  The fact that the subsets are not connected is irrelevant.

Comment: So what do you mean when you say "size of min-cut"? Is that not the minimum number of edges you have to remove to get two partitions?
How else do you define "min-cut"?

Comment: The **size** or **weight**  of a cut is the number of edges joining the two subsets.  That's what you want to minimize.